# MongoDB C# Driver 'Remote certificate is invalid'

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm having an issue with connecting to a MongoDB using the C# Driver. The code works on other systems, but for some reason doesn't want to work on mine. I'm using the latest Mongo .net Drivers and core/bson, and have the correct connection settings.

My full error is:

```
A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = ReadPreferenceServerSelector{ ReadPreference = { Mode = Primary, TagSets = [] } }, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "Sharded", Type : "Sharded", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/lon-mongos1.objectrocket.com:33138" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/lon-mongos1.objectrocket.com:33138", State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
 at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
 at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
 at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
 at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
 at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.SslStreamFactory.<CreateStreamAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
 at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.<OpenHelperAsync>d__47.MoveNext()
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.<OpenHelperAsync>d__47.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
 at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ClusterableServer.<HeartbeatAsync>d__42.MoveNext()" }] }.
```

I've taken a look into the certificates locally and can't see anything that would suggest it isn't valid on my side.

Being from a non-mongo background this isn't something that I'm too familiar with, but wondered if anybody could shed some light on what I might be doing wrong here?

I'm running W7 SP1 with VS2015.

Edit: I have tried the approach of validating the certificates regardless but this has not proved to make any difference, too.

I do run fiddler regularly, but I have deleted the certificates for fiddler and currently I am not running it.

Answer (score 4):

In most cases this error appears when MongoDb uses self-signed SSL certificate and it cannot pass standard validation with root certs installed locally. You can simply disable this validation by specifying the following query parameter in the connection string:

```
sslVerifyCertificate=false
```

if you configure MongoDb driver with c# code:

```
var client = new MongoClient();
client.Settings.VerifySslCertificate = false;
```

Comment: fyi This is not available in 2.3. will cause iis web.config exception

Comment: The latest MongoDB.Driver version at this moment is 2.18 and it has 'VeriftySslCertificate' setting.